# overcommitted kvm performance issue

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, virtualization, kvm

I'm having performance problem when I run a benchmark program on a virtual machine with 1 pCPU and 4 vCPUs. I used mpstat to investigate about what might be causing the problem and *how* it is causing the problem. it shows an increase in steal time, idle time and sys time.

here is output of mpstat on my virtual machine when I run my program:

```
  CPU    %usr   %nice   %sys %iowait    %irq    %soft  %steal  %guest  %idle
  all    3.14    0.00    8.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   58.29    0.00  30.57
    0    4.60    0.00    8.05    0.00    0.00    0.00   64.37    0.00  22.99
    1    2.27    0.00    5.68    0.00    0.00    0.00   53.41    0.00  38.64
    2    3.37    0.00    8.99    0.00    0.00    0.00   61.80    0.00  25.84
    3    3.45    0.00    8.05    0.00    0.00    0.00   54.02    0.00  34.48
```

and here is its output on a host machine (when I run the program):

```
  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %idle
  all   91.80    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   7.70
    0   91.00    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   8.50
    1   93.03    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   6.47
    2   90.59    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   8.91
    3   93.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   7.00
```

I know that (from [ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/linux390/perf/tuning_rec_CPUtimes_virtual.html)):

> Steal time is the percentage of time a virtual CPU waits for a real
>   CPU while the hypervisor is servicing another virtual processor.

I know this increase in steal time is maybe because my virtual machine is over-committed, but I wonder why I did not have this problem with other programs that I tested. and I don't know why the idle time increases as well.

the source code for my test program is quite large and I posted it [here](https://github.com/zeinabm/streamcluster) in github. I don't know if it is important or not but this code does some busy waiting. here is the code where busy waiting happens:

```
int parsec_barrier_wait(parsec_barrier_t *barrier) {
  int master;
  int rv;

  if(barrier==NULL) return EINVAL;

  rv = pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier->mutex);
  if(rv != 0) return rv;

  //A (necessarily) unsynchronized polling loop followed by fall-back blocking
  if(!barrier->is_arrival_phase) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->mutex);
    volatile spin_counter_t i=0;
    while(!barrier->is_arrival_phase && i<SPIN_COUNTER_MAX) i++;
    while((rv=pthread_mutex_trylock(&barrier->mutex)) == EBUSY);
    if(rv != 0) return rv;

    //Fall back to normal waiting on condition variable if necessary
    while(!barrier->is_arrival_phase) {
      rv = pthread_cond_wait(&barrier->cond, &barrier->mutex);
      if(rv != 0) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->mutex);
        return rv;
      }
    }
  }

  //We are guaranteed to be in an arrival phase, proceed with barrier synchronization
  master = (barrier->n == 0); //Make first thread at barrier the master
  barrier->n++;
  if(barrier->n >= barrier->max) {
    //This is the last thread to arrive, don't wait instead
    //start a new departure phase and wake up all other threads
    barrier->is_arrival_phase = 0;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&barrier->cond);
  } else {
    //wait for last thread to arrive (which will end arrival phase)
    //we use again an unsynchronized polling loop followed by synchronized fall-back blocking
    if(barrier->is_arrival_phase) {
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->mutex);
      volatile spin_counter_t i=0;
      while(barrier->is_arrival_phase && i<SPIN_COUNTER_MAX) i++;
      while((rv=pthread_mutex_trylock(&barrier->mutex)) == EBUSY);
      if(rv != 0) return rv;

      //Fall back to normal waiting on condition variable if necessary
      while(barrier->is_arrival_phase) {
        rv = pthread_cond_wait(&barrier->cond, &barrier->mutex);
        if(rv != 0) {
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->mutex);
          return rv;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  barrier->n--;
  //last thread to leave barrier starts a new arrival phase
  if(barrier->n == 0) {
    barrier->is_arrival_phase = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&barrier->cond);
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->mutex);

  return (master ? PARSEC_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD : 0);
}
```

any idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The steal time is probably higher simply because you have higher overall vcpu utilization (from spinning). The idle time is a little more unusual, but I would suspect it represents non-virtualized CPU time.

Comment: @Sneftel would you explain more, please? what do you mean by non-virtualized CPU time? does the VM know that its CPU is virtualized?